# VIM 80 Column Highlight for specific filenames

Tags: vim, vi

I know how to highlight past 80 characters using vim for all of my files using the following in my vimrc:

```
if exists('+colorcolumn')
  set colorcolumn=80
else
  au BufWinEnter * let w:m2=matchadd('ErrorMsg', '\%>80v.\+', -1)
endif
```

But is there a way to apply this to only certain file names? I am somewhat familiar with the autocmd but I can't seem to make it work. I don't want it to apply to file TYPES, but only a certain file name. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Autocommand mechanism, that you actually already use, is exactly what you need. Your `au` line is autocommand, and it basic form takes 3 parameters:

- *event* - which is `BufWinEnter` in your case, meaning that it will run after buffer is displayed in a window,
- *pattern* - which is `*` in your case, meaning that it will match all file names,
- *command* - which is to long to retype it here, but it's a command that will be run on *event* if file name matches *pattern*

So what you actually need is to change your `*` to a proper pattern (see `:h autocmd-patterns`), like for example `*.txt` to match all files with `.txt` extension.

Since you use auto command only in case there is no `+colorcolumn` feature enabled, you should also change it to auto command. Since `colorcolumn` is a per window, not per buffer setting, it's unfortunately not that easy and involves saving and restoring the last value. Something like:

```
:au BufWinEnter *.txt set colorcolumn=80
:au BufWinEnter *.txt let w:lastcc=&colorcolumn
:au BufWinLeave *.txt let colorcolumn=w:lastcc
```

Those are simple examples, it depends on you how sophisticated you will make it. You may also consider which *event* you want to use (like wrapping all this inside of function and using function call as a command, for example).

Comment: Be warned that `'colorcolumn'` is a local to a window not a buffer. So you will need to play with `BufLeave` event

Answer (score 0):

This one work for me:

```
augroup collumnLimit
   autocmd!
   autocmd BufRead,BufEnter YourFileNameHere
                    \ highlight CollumnLimit ctermbg=Red guibg=Red
   let collumnLimit = 79
   let pattern =
            \ '\%<' . (collumnLimit+1) . 'v.\%>' . collumnLimit . 'v'
   autocmd BufRead,BufEnter YourFileNameHere
            \ let w:m1=matchadd('CollumnLimit', pattern, -1)
augroup END
```